# Issue in installing phpmyadmin in Laravel Homestead

Tags: laravel, homestead, apt

I am trying to install phpmyadmin using this command: `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`
But getting the error bellow:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    phpmyadmin :
>
> Depends: libapache2-mod-php5 but it is not going to be installed or
>                          libapache2-mod-php5filter but it is not going to be installed or
>                          php5-cgi but it is not going to be installed or
>                          php5-fpm but it is not going to be installed or
>                          php5 but it is not going to be installed
>
> Depends: php5-mysql but it is not going to be installed or
>                          php5-mysqli but it is not installable or
>                          php5-mysqlnd but it is not going to be installed
>
> Depends: php5-mcrypt but it is not going to be installed
>
> Depends: php5-json but it is not going to be installed
>
> Depends: php-gettext but it is not going to be installed
>                 Recommends: php5-gd but it is not going to be installed
>
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Homestead installs PHP7 with Nginx. The phpMyAdmin package expects PHP5 and Apache. You'll need to install it yourself per http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html, or better yet, install something like Sequel Pro (Mac) or Navicat/MySQL Workbench (Windows) to access it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You said you're using Homestead which operates outside of the Debian package manager. The ideal solution in this case is to simply [install phpMyAdmin manually](https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Quick_Install) because relying on the package manager is going to try to install all the dependencies that you don't want.

Under normal conditions, you have to install the dependencies listed.

My `apt-get` makes these suggestions automatically:

```
# apt-get install phpmyadmin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-image-2.6-486 linux-image-2.6-686
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  dbconfig-common php-gettext php-tcpdf
Suggested packages:
  php5-imagick
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dbconfig-common php-gettext php-tcpdf phpmyadmin
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 15.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 46.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

I don't see anything special in my configuration file that would cause this, so you might look at yours to see if you're preventing it somehow.

Anyway, the immediate answer is to just tell apt to install the missing packages:

`$ sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysqlnd php5-mcrypt php5-json php-gettext`

However, you also have this:

> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Which is a bit odd; you can fix broken packages with `$ sudo apt-get -f install`.